# Helipad Co-ordinates of LunarLander v2 openai gym

Tags: reinforcement-learning, openai-gym, q-learning, sarsa

I am trying to implement a custom lunar lander environment by taking help from already existing LunarLanderv2. https://github.com/openai/gym/blob/master/gym/envs/box2d/lunar_lander.py

I'm having a hard time figuring out the pole co-ordinates of the helipad. I intend to find the ideal landing position of the shuttle.

Answer (score -1):

Thanks to Mr. Shiva Verma
https://towardsdatascience.com/solving-lunar-lander-openaigym-reinforcement-learning-785675066197
and openai https://gym.openai.com/envs/LunarLander-v2/
The landing zone is always (0,0) for a discrete lunar landing problem.